# How to correctly setup Hyperledger Fabric Channel Policy? (Failure to satisfy Policy on Channel Creation)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

TL;DR
How to solve this error: "Error on creating channel: Policy not satisfied"?

Troubleshooting Questions I have:

- What value to use for ordererTLSHostnameOverride?
- What names should be used in Policy Rules?
- Where should they be first defined?
- Am I missing/using wrong environmental variables in my CLI?
- Besides configtx.yaml, where else should I look for issues?

---

Update 2020-9-22B
Nikhil Gupta suggested that this is a problem with the cert used to submit the request.

After taking a deeper look at the Orderer server log, I found confirmation:

```
2020-09-22 22:09:54.351 UTC [policies] SignatureSetToValidIdentities -> WARN 471 invalid identity: certificate subject=CN=peer0.org1.example.com,OU=COP,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US serialnumber=268337738708423250738667250199689187829 error="the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
```

Oddly, I don't ever use the CN value of "peer0.org1.example.com."  (I grep'd my entire project directory - I don't use that name once!)

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57662562/when-i-try-to-create-a-channel-using-hyperledger-fabric-the-request-fails) post, tried pulling the system genesis block to inspect the root certificate used, but get a `Expect block, but got status: &{FORBIDDEN}` error.  I believe this means there is an issue with my MSP (per ref [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58968042/unable-to-fetch-a-block-from-the-channel-in-hyperledger-fabric) and [2](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-8492?focusedCommentId=40719&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-40719)).

I'm wondering if this could be caused by my Peer and Orderer nodes each using their own CAs?

---

Update 2020-9-22A
I tried using admincerts instead of NodeOUs figuring that this could help me troubleshoot the issue.  Instead, I got an error: "administrators must be declared when no admin ou classification is set."

(I copied the Peer Admin user signcerts cert.pem to
organizations/ordererOrganizations/ORG/msp/admincerts folder, and
did the same for the Orderer Admin.)

---

I am trying to create a Fabric channel on a new, custom network (using the CLI per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63961687/13856851)), and am getting the following error:

```
/Channel/Application not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied.
```

This is the command I'm using to create the channel:

```
peer channel create -o $host:1050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME --ordererTLSHostnameOverride OEM_Orderer -f ./channel-artifacts/${CHANNEL_NAME}.tx --outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/${CHANNEL_NAME}.block --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA
```

I'm not certain I'm using the correct value for "ordererTLSHostnameOverride."  (I've tried using the Orderer Docker Service name, the Orderer MSPID and the Orderer Org Name.)

Here is the relevant portion of the output:

```
2020-09-18 19:30:45.877 UTC [grpc] WithKeepaliveParams -> DEBU 030 Adjusting keepalive ping interval to minimum period of 10s
2020-09-18 19:30:45.877 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 031 parsed scheme: ""
2020-09-18 19:30:45.877 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 032 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2020-09-18 19:30:45.878 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 033 ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{oem.scm.cloudns.asia:1050  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}
2020-09-18 19:30:45.878 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 034 ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2020-09-18 19:30:45.878 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 035 Channel switches to new LB policy "pick_first"
2020-09-18 19:30:45.879 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 036 Subchannel Connectivity change to CONNECTING
2020-09-18 19:30:45.879 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 037 Subchannel picks a new address "oem.scm.cloudns.asia:1050" to connect
2020-09-18 19:30:45.880 UTC [grpc] UpdateSubConnState -> DEBU 038 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0004bdbe0, {CONNECTING <nil>}
2020-09-18 19:30:45.880 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 039 Channel Connectivity change to CONNECTING
2020-09-18 19:30:45.888 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 03a Subchannel Connectivity change to READY
2020-09-18 19:30:45.888 UTC [grpc] UpdateSubConnState -> DEBU 03b pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0004bdbe0, {READY <nil>}
2020-09-18 19:30:45.889 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 03c Channel Connectivity change to READY
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error validating channel creation transaction for new channel 'supply-chain-network', could not successfully apply update to template configuration: error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied
```

Additional questions related to this output:

- Does "DEBU 032 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme" indicate a failure to use my defined policy?
- Does this line seem to indicate an issue:  "DEBU 038 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0004bdbe0, {CONNECTING }"

Configtx.yaml: (some lines at end commented out for troubleshooting)

```
     1  # Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
     2  #
     3  # SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
     4  #
     5  # Pulled from: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/sampleconfig/configtx.yaml
     6  ---
     7  ################################################################################
     8  #
     9  #   ORGANIZATIONS
    10  #
    11  #   This section defines the organizational identities that can be referenced
    12  #   in the configuration profiles.
    13  #
    14  ################################################################################
    15  Organizations:
    16  
    17      - &Orderer-OEM
    18          Name: Orderer-OEM
    19          SkipAsForeign: false
    20          ID: Orderer-OEM-MSP
    21          MSPDir: ./organizations/ordererOrganizations/OEM/msp/
    22          Policies: &Orderer-OEMPolicies
    23              Readers:
    24                  Type: Signature
    25                  Rule: "OR('Orderer-OEM-MSP.member')"
    26              Writers:
    27                  Type: Signature
    28                  Rule: "OR('Orderer-OEM-MSP.member')"
    29              Admins:
    30                  Type: Signature
    31                  Rule: "OR('Orderer-OEM-MSP.admin')"
    32              Endorsement:
    33                  Type: Signature
    34                  Rule: "OR('Orderer-OEM-MSP.member')"
    35          OrdererEndpoints:
    36              - OEM_Orderer:1050
    37  
    38      - &OEM
    39          Name: OEM
    40          SkipAsForeign: false
    41          ID: OEM-MSP
    42          MSPDir: ./organizations/peerOrganizations/OEM/msp/
    43          Policies: &OEMPolicies
    44              Readers:
    45                  Type: Signature
    46                  Rule: "OR('OEM-MSP.admin','OEM-MSP.peer','OEM-MSP.client')"
    47              Writers:
    48                  Type: Signature
    49                  Rule: "OR('OEM-MSP.admin','OEM-MSP.client')"
    50              Admins:
    51                  Type: Signature
    52                  Rule: "OR('OEM-MSP.admin')"
    53              Endorsement:
    54                  Type: Signature
    55                  Rule: "OR('OEM-MSP.peer')"
    56          AnchorPeers:
    57              - Host: $host
    58                Port: 1051
    59  
    60  
    61      - &S11
    62          Name: S11
    63          SkipAsForeign: false
    64          ID: S11-MSP
    65          MSPDir: ./organizations/peerOrganizations/S11/msp
    66          Policies: &S11Policies
    67              Readers:
    68                  Type: Signature
    69                  Rule: "OR('S11-MSP.admin','S11-MSP.peer','S11-MSP.client')"
    70              Writers:
    71                  Type: Signature
    72                  Rule: "OR('S11-MSP.admin','S11-MSP.client')"
    73              Admins:
    74                  Type: Signature
    75                  Rule: "OR('S11-MSP.admin')"
    76              Endorsement:
    77                  Type: Signature
    78                  Rule: "OR('S11-MSP.peer')"
    79          AnchorPeers:
    80              - Host: $host2
    81                Port: 1051
    82  
    83  
    84  
    85  Capabilities:
    86      Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
    87          V2_0: true
    88  
    89      Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
    90          V2_0: true
    91  
    92      Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
    93          V2_0: true
    94  
    95  ################################################################################
    96  #
    97  #   APPLICATION
    98  #
    99  #   This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
   100  #   genesis block for application-related parameters.
   101  #
   102  ################################################################################
   103  Application: &ApplicationDefaults  #policy defaults for system resources
   104      ACLs: &ACLsDefault
   105  
   106          _lifecycle/CheckCommitReadiness: /Channel/Application/Writers
   107          _lifecycle/CommitChaincodeDefinition: /Channel/Application/Writers
   108          _lifecycle/QueryChaincodeDefinition: /Channel/Application/Writers
   109          _lifecycle/QueryChaincodeDefinitions: /Channel/Application/Writers
   110          lscc/ChaincodeExists: /Channel/Application/Readers
   111          lscc/GetDeploymentSpec: /Channel/Application/Readers
   112          lscc/GetChaincodeData: /Channel/Application/Readers
   113          lscc/GetInstantiatedChaincodes: /Channel/Application/Readers
   114          qscc/GetChainInfo: /Channel/Application/Readers
   115          qscc/GetBlockByNumber: /Channel/Application/Readers
   116          qscc/GetBlockByHash: /Channel/Application/Readers
   117          qscc/GetTransactionByID: /Channel/Application/Readers
   118          qscc/GetBlockByTxID: /Channel/Application/Readers
   119          cscc/GetConfigBlock: /Channel/Application/Readers
   120          peer/Propose: /Channel/Application/Writers
   121          peer/ChaincodeToChaincode: /Channel/Application/Writers
   122          event/Block: /Channel/Application/Readers
   123          event/FilteredBlock: /Channel/Application/Readers
   124  
   125      Organizations: # lists the orgs participating on the application side of the network. 
   126        - *OEM
   127        - *S11
   128  
   129      # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
   130      # For Application policies, their canonical path is
   131      #   /Channel/Application/<PolicyName>
   132      Policies: &ApplicationDefaultPolicies
   133          LifecycleEndorsement:
   134              Type: ImplicitMeta
   135              Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
   136          Endorsement:
   137              Type: ImplicitMeta
   138              Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
   139          Readers:
   140              Type: ImplicitMeta
   141              Rule: "ANY Readers"
   142          Writers:
   143              Type: ImplicitMeta
   144              Rule: "ANY Writers"
   145          Admins:
   146              Type: ImplicitMeta
   147              Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
   148  
   149      # Capabilities describes the application level capabilities, see the
   150      # dedicated Capabilities section elsewhere in this file for a full
   151      # description
   152      Capabilities:
   153          <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
   154  
   155  ################################################################################
   156  #
   157  #   ORDERER
   158  #
   159  #   This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
   160  #   genesis block for orderer related parameters.
   161  #
   162  ################################################################################
   163  Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
   164  
   165      OrdererType: solo
   166  
   167      BatchTimeout: 2s
   168  
   169      BatchSize:
   170  
   171          MaxMessageCount: 500
   172  
   173          AbsoluteMaxBytes: 10 MB
   174  
   175          PreferredMaxBytes: 2 MB
   176  
   177      MaxChannels: 0 #0=unlimited number of channels allowed 
   178  
   179  
   180      # EtcdRaft defines configuration which must be set when the "etcdraft"
   181      # orderertype is chosen.
   182      EtcdRaft:
   183          # The set of Raft replicas for this network. For the etcd/raft-based
   184          # implementation, we expect every replica to also be an OSN. Therefore,
   185          # a subset of the host:port items enumerated in this list should be
   186          # replicated under the Orderer.Addresses key above.
   187          Consenters:
   188              - Host: Orderer-OEM
   189                Port: 1050
   190                ClientTLSCert: ./organizations/ordererOrganizations/OEM/orderers/Orderer2/tls/server.crt
   191                ServerTLSCert: ./organizations/ordererOrganizations/OEM/orderers/Orderer2/tls/server.crt
   192  #            - Host: Orderer-S11
   193  #              Port: 7050
   194  #              ClientTLSCert: ./organizations/ordererOrganizations/S11/orderers/Orderer1/tls/server.crt  
   195  #              ServerTLSCert: ./organizations/ordererOrganizations/S11/orderers/Orderer1/tls/server.crt   
   196  #            - Host: raft2.example.com
   197  #              Port: 7050
   198  #              ClientTLSCert: path/to/ClientTLSCert2
   199  #              ServerTLSCert: path/to/ServerTLSCert2
   200  
   201          Options:
   202              TickInterval: 500ms
   203  
   204              ElectionTick: 10
   205  
   206              HeartbeatTick: 1
   207  
   208              MaxInflightBlocks: 5
   209  
   210              SnapshotIntervalSize: 16 MB
   211  
   212      # Organizations lists the orgs participating on the orderer side of the
   213      # network.
   214      Organizations:
   215  
   216      # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
   217      # For Orderer policies, their canonical path is
   218      #   /Channel/Orderer/<PolicyName>
   219      Policies:
   220          Readers:
   221              Type: ImplicitMeta
   222              Rule: "ANY Readers"
   223          Writers:
   224              Type: ImplicitMeta
   225              Rule: "ANY Writers"
   226          Admins:
   227              Type: ImplicitMeta
   228              Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
   229          # BlockValidation specifies what signatures must be included in the block
   230          # from the orderer for the peer to validate it.
   231          BlockValidation:
   232              Type: ImplicitMeta
   233              Rule: "ANY Writers"
   234  
   235      Capabilities:
   236          <<: *OrdererCapabilities
   237  
   238  ################################################################################
   239  #
   240  #   CHANNEL
   241  #
   242  #   This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
   243  #   genesis block for channel related parameters.
   244  #
   245  ################################################################################
   246  Channel: &ChannelDefaults
   247      # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
   248      # For Channel policies, their canonical path is
   249      #   /Channel/<PolicyName>
   250      Policies:
   251          # Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API
   252          Readers:
   253              Type: ImplicitMeta
   254              Rule: "ANY Readers"
   255          # Who may invoke the 'Broadcast' API
   256          Writers:
   257              Type: ImplicitMeta
   258              Rule: "ANY Writers"
   259          # By default, who may modify elements at this config level
   260          Admins:
   261              Type: ImplicitMeta
   262              Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
   263  
   264  
   265      # Capabilities describes the channel level capabilities, see the
   266      # dedicated Capabilities section elsewhere in this file for a full
   267      # description
   268      Capabilities:
   269          <<: *ChannelCapabilities
   270  
   271  ################################################################################
   272  #
   273  #   PROFILES
   274  #
   275  #   Different configuration profiles may be encoded here to be specified as
   276  #   parameters to the configtxgen tool. The profiles which specify consortiums
   277  #   are to be used for generating the orderer genesis block. With the correct
   278  #   consortium members defined in the orderer genesis block, channel creation
   279  #   requests may be generated with only the org member names and a consortium
   280  #   name.
   281  #
   282  ################################################################################
   283  Profiles:
   284  
   285      # SampleDevModeEtcdRaft defines a configuration that differs from the
   286      # SampleDevModeSolo one only in that it uses the etcd/raft-based orderer.
   287      SampleDevModeEtcdRaft:
   288          <<: *ChannelDefaults
   289          Orderer:
   290              <<: *OrdererDefaults
   291              OrdererType: etcdraft
   292              Organizations:
   293                  - <<: *Orderer-OEM
   294                    Policies:
   295                        <<: *Orderer-OEMPolicies
   296                        Admins:
   297                            Type: Signature
   298                            Rule: "OR('Orderer-OEM-MSP.admin')"
   299  #                          Rule: "OR('Orderer-OEM.admin')"
   300          Application:
   301              <<: *ApplicationDefaults
   302              Organizations:
   303                  - <<: *OEM
   304  #                - <<: *S11
   305                    Policies:
   306                        <<: *OEMPolicies
   307                        Admins:
   308                            Type: Signature
   309  #                          Rule: "OR('OEM-MSP.admin','S11-MSP.admin')"
   310                            Rule: "OR('OEM-MSP.admin')"
   311  #                          Rule: "OR('OEM.admin')"
   312          Consortiums:
   313              SupplyChain:
   314                  Organizations:
   315                      - <<: *OEM
   316  #                    - <<: *S11
   317                        Policies:
   318                            <<: *OEMPolicies
   319                            Admins:
   320                                Type: Signature
   321  #                              Rule: "OR('OEM-MSP.admin','S11-MSP.admin')"
   322                                Rule: "OR('OEM-MSP.admin')"
   323  #                              Rule: "OR('OEM.admin')"
   324  
   325      SampleSupplyChainChannel:
   326          Consortium: SupplyChain
   327          <<: *ChannelDefaults
   328          Application:
   329              <<: *ApplicationDefaults
   330              Organizations:
   331                  - <<: *OEM
   332  #                - <<: *S11
   333  #                  Policies:
   334  #                      <<: *OEMPolicies
   335  #                      Admins:
   336  #                          Type: Signature
   337  #                          Rule: "OR('OEM-MSP.admin','S11-MSP.admin')"
```

Docker file for Peer, Orderer, and cli:

```
     1  version: '3.8'
     2  
     3  services:
     4  
     5    Peer:
     6      image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.2
     7      ports:
     8        - "8051:8051"
     9      networks:
    10        - scm-test
    11      #depends_on:   #is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode
    12      #  - Orderer
    13      deploy:  #options may be removed if not required
    14        mode: replicated #global=1 container/node; replicated=specific # distributed per requirements
    15        replicas: 1 #can only be used with replicated mode
    16        placement:
    17          constraints:
    18            - "node.role==manager"
    19            - "node.hostname==OEM"
    20          #max_replicas_per_node: 1
    21        endpoint_mode: vip #options are vip (virtual IP) or dnsrr (DNS round-robin)
    22      environment:
    23        - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
    24        - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG #change to INFO if too verbose (once working)
    25        - CORE_Peer_TLS_ENABLED=true
    26        - CORE_Peer_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
    27        - CORE_Peer_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
    28        - CORE_Peer_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
    29        - CORE_Peer_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
    30        # Peer specific variables
    31        - CORE_Peer_ID=Peer2
    32        - CORE_Peer_ADDRESS=$host:8051
    33        - CORE_Peer_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8051
    34        - CORE_Peer_CHAINCODEADDRESS=$host:8052
    35        - CORE_Peer_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8052
    36        - CORE_Peer_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=$host:8051
    37        - CORE_Peer_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=$host:8051
    38        - CORE_Peer_LOCALMSPID=OEM-MSP
    39      command: peer node start
    40      volumes:
    41        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
    42        - ./organizations/peerOrganizations/$ORG/peers/$Peer2/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
    43        - ./organizations/peerOrganizations/$ORG/peers/$Peer2/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    44        - ./organizations/peerOrganizations/$ORG/peers/$Peer2/peerData:/var/hyperledger/production
    45  #    working_dir: 
    46      container_name: Peer2 #is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode
    47  
    48  
    49    Orderer:
    50      image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.2
    51      ports:
    52        - "1050:1050"
    53      networks:
    54        - scm-test
    55      deploy:  #options may be removed if not required
    56        mode: replicated #global=1 container/node; replicated=specific # distributed per requirements
    57        replicas: 1 #can only be used with replicated mode
    58        placement:
    59          constraints:
    60            - "node.role==manager"
    61            - "node.hostname==OEM"
    62        endpoint_mode: vip #options are vip (virtual IP) or dnsrr (DNS round-robin)
    63      environment:
    64        - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
    65        - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
    66        - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=1050
    67        - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
    68        - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block/genesis_block.pb
    69        - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=Orderer-OEM-MSP
    70        - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
    71        - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
    72        - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
    73        - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
    74        - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    75        - ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
    76        - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
    77        - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
    78        - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
    79        - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    80      command: orderer
    81      volumes:
    82        - ./system-genesis-block/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
    83        - ./organizations/ordererOrganizations/$ORG/orderers/$Orderer2/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
    84        - ./organizations/ordererOrganizations/$ORG/orderers/$Orderer2/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
    85        - ./organizations/ordererOrganizations/$ORG/orderers/$Orderer2/ordererData:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    86      container_name: Orderer2 #is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode
    87  
    88  
    89    cli:
    90      image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:2.2
    91      networks:
    92        - scm-test
    93      depends_on:   #is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode
    94        - Peer
    95      deploy:  #options may be removed if not required
    96        mode: replicated #global=1 container/node; replicated=specific # distributed per requirements
    97        replicas: 1 #can only be used with replicated mode
    98        placement:
    99          constraints:
   100            - "node.role==manager"
   101            - "node.hostname==OEM"
   102          #max_replicas_per_node: 1
   103        endpoint_mode: vip #options are vip (virtual IP) or dnsrr (DNS round-robin)
   104      tty: true
   105      stdin_open: true
   106      environment:
   107        - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
   108        - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
   109        - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG #change to INFO if too verbose (once working)
   110        - CORE_Peer_ID=cli
   111        - CORE_Peer_ADDRESS=$host:8051
   112        - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=OEM-MSP
   113  #      - CORE_Peer_mspConfigPath=/etc/hyperledger/AdminMsp
   114  #      - CORE_Peer_mspConfigPath=/etc/hyperledger/organizations/ordererOrganizations/$ORG/users/Admin@${$Orderer2}/msp/
   115        - CORE_Peer_mspConfigPath=/etc/hyperledger/organizations/peerOrganizations/$ORG/users/Admin@${ORG}/msp/
   116        - CORE_CHAINCODE_KEEPALIVE=10
   117        - CORE_Peer_TLS_ENABLED=true
   118        - CORE_Peer_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
   119        - CORE_Peer_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
   120        - CORE_Peer_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
   121        - CORE_Peer_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
   122        - CORE_Peer_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8051
   123        - CORE_Peer_CHAINCODEADDRESS=$host:8052
   124        - CORE_Peer_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8052
   125        - CORE_Peer_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=$host:8051
   126        - CORE_Peer_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=$host:8051
   127  #Environment varibles used for channel creation:
   128        - ORDERER_CA=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/organizations/ordererOrganizations/$ORG/orderers/$Orderer2/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.${Orderer2}-cert.pem  #WARNING hardcoded
   129        - host=$host
   130        - ORG=$ORG
   131        - orgmsp=Orderer-OEM-MSP  #WARNING HARDCODED!
   132        - CHANNEL_NAME=supply-chain-network  #WARNING HARDCODED! 
   133      command: /bin/bash
   134      volumes:
   135        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
   136        - ./organizations/peerOrganizations:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/organizations/peerOrganizations
   137        - ./organizations/ordererOrganizations:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/organizations/ordererOrganizations
   138        - ./organizations/peerOrganizations/$ORG/peers/$Peer2/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
   139        - ./channel-artifacts:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/channel-artifacts
   140      working_dir: /etc/hyperledger/fabric/
   141  
   142  
   143  networks:
   144    scm-test:
   145      external: true #true indicates network has been created outside of compose; compose does not attempt to create it
```

Comment: At this point, because I have not been able to track down the problem (beside it being a certificate issue), I am returning to the "tried and true" sample test-network and working my way back from there.  If I find the root cause of this issue, I will report back here.

Comment: Where you able to figure out the root cause ?

Answer (score 0):

Since your error states that the Admin sub-policy is not satisfied, it may indicate that you try to create your channel as a non-Admin user. One can try to provide additional Admin parameters to "peer channel create"

```sh
--clientauth --keyfile $ORDERER_CONF/Admin@${ORGANIZATION}/tls/client.key 
--certfile $ORDERER_CONF/Admin@${ORGANIZATION}/tls/client.crt
```

One can find these certificates in ordererOrganizations/..